# View swap using push animation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, nsviewanimation

I want to swap out one view with another by pushing the old view aside to slide in a new view (the kCATransitionPush type). To use CoreAnimation I need to work with CALayers with my views. The problem is that attaching a backing layer to my window content view through setWantsLayer distorts everything in the view.

I'm not sure if this has something to do with the fact that I'm using a subclass of NSWindow called MAAttachedWindow (http://mattgemmell.com/source), which is a HUD style transparent popup window of sorts that attaches to another element on the screen.

I can provide screenshots of this distortion if needed. I got the animation working through NSViewAnimation, but as many others have experienced, NSViewAnimation is terribly slow. I'd rather use CoreAnimation but this issue prevents me from using it.

Any insight is greatly appreciated

Comment: “I can provide screenshots of this distortion if needed.” Please do.

Comment: You also might try changing this to a regular window to test your theory. If the problem persists, then you'll probably want to describe a bit more about how you're approaching your solution.

Comment: Sometimes running your own animation piggy-backed on NSAnimation is the way to go; you probably don’t have to shift to CA.

Comment: Got some screenshots. Before attaching the layer: http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/43/screenshot20091110at412.png And after: http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/2558/screenshot20091110at424.png You can see that the text is noticeably smoother without the layer, and the vertical scroll bar gets a black background for some reason. I don't know why this is happening because I'm not doing anything fancy with the layer. And this doesnt happen on a normal window. NSViewAnimation works for this, but its slow. Any suggestions on how to speed it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to possibility of non-integral coordinates, to me the text appears to have been drawn into a non-opaque buffer. The LCD-aware Quartz text antialiasing doesn't work if it is drawn atop a non-opaque background color and *then* composited. Rather, your layer/view must fill the background with an opaque background color and then draw text above it.

One workaround for this that we've played with is to:

- Draw your translucent background.
- Draw your text with the background color, alpha=1, *and* add a stroke to the text of the same color, picking the stroke width to encompass the antialiasing area (beware resolution independence here).
- Draw the text as normal, above this “landing pad”.

The issue with the scroller is possibly that the scroller is claiming -isOpaque but it isn't. Appropriate twiddling of the opaqueness and background color rendering should help.

Answer (score 0):

Given your saying the problem doesn't occur with normal windows, it's time to hawk-eye MAAttachedWindow. One of the first things I see when the window is created in this code is:

```
[self useOptimizedDrawing:YES];
```

What happens if you comment that line out? The next thing to look at is the drawing code. Also, the -_redisplay method disables/reenables screen updates, updating geometry and the background while this occurs. All of this would make me suspicious of its interaction with layer-backed views and animation.

Comment: Uncommenting that line didn't have much effect, but yeah its probably an issue with MAAttachedWindow. I think it was written before CoreAnimation was introduced. Rather than try and pick through the code to find whats wrong, I might try subclassing NSAnimation and rolling my own. Would that be a good solution?

Comment: Probably best posed as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at how distortion increases  makes me think that one or more of your views' bounds or frame are not integral.

Comment: I'm not quite sure by what you mean by "integral"

Comment: Also, I tried what you suggested with NSAnimation. I created a subclass of it and my animation works, but its just as slow as NSViewAnimation

Comment: He means that the origin of your view's frame does not appear to lie on integer values for X and Y.  If your view has an origin of (100.2, 200.5), you might run into the blurriness you're seeing.  Correcting the origin to (100, 200) would remove that blurriness.

Comment: Since the blurring is progressive across the image it’s probably the size of something that’s not integral, not necessarily the origin.